# if I am starting to see the veins in my arms, am I losing body fat?

Tags: weightlifting, weight-loss, body-fat

I am:

- 21 year old male
- 5 foot 7
- 94.4Kg
- 32.2% body fat (last time I was checked)

Currently on a lean bulk diet with 5 very intense days of strength/weight training and weekends I actively rest by doing cardio.

As title suggests, I was wondering if I am losing body fat if I am starting to see the veins in my arms. I have never been vascular in the past and have only currently noticed my veins slightly. They become much more pronounced as I workout, mainly on days where I am going for high reps. What is causing this and am I losing body fat?

Comment: I wouldn't think so. More likely it's just increased blood flow to the parts of the body that are working, which is a recognized phenomenon in bodybuilding called "pump".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the adaptations that occurs with exercise, is that the body will grow new blood vessels into the muscles for greater blood flow/oxygenation. The term for this is angiogenesis. It's a normal byproduct of aerobic and endurance exercise, and to a lesser extent anaerobic activity. Also, your existing blood vessels will expand some to accommodate the increased demand for blood flow. This will also account for some of the engorgement you see as you work out, as part of the vascular response is to shift more blood flow towards superficial (close to the skin) blood vessels to aid in cooling.

As you get more and more lean, they will also appear more pronounced as you do not have as much fat obscuring them.

[image: Cyclists legs, purportedly Lance Armstrong]